# win32diskimage canot launch

Tags: windows, microsoft-runtime-library

I downloaded the tool from http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/files/latest/download
but I cannot launch it after installed, I worked under windows 7 64bit and it it brings me this window:
[image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading this:

- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328)

Then it should run. Also, open the application as administrator.

Comment: thks a lot, i have tried run as administrator and fixed Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  Redistributable with  vcredist_x86 but it still not work  when i close the window it show the bad module is libstdc++-6.dll  and i have Qt5.5 installed on my windows before ,dose it probably the matters of Qt?

Comment: this dll is used by qt5.5 / has something to do with it i guess. please write down the error message and then we look again :)

Comment: 问题签名:
  问题事件名称: APPCRASH
  应用程序名: Win32DiskImager.exe
  应用程序版本: 0.9.5.0
  应用程序时间戳: 53126554
  故障模块名称: libstdc++-6.dll
  故障模块版本: 0.0.0.0
  故障模块时间戳: 516ee7b6
  异常代码: 40000015
  异常偏移: 00019d8d
  OS 版本: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  区域设置 ID: 2052
  其他信息 1: bf1e
  其他信息 2: bf1e9a9d85caf4752c81cca5c875ead9
  其他信息 3: 66b3
  其他信息 4: 66b3d15a43c483097061fe9ccaa73f7a

is it what you need?

Comment: try download the dll from http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?libstdc%2B%2B-6 (right - manual fix) with this instruction : http://www.dll-files.com/unzip.php then restart and install win32diskimage again ...say if it helps , btw is there a reason that you must use this tool or can you try someting else like http://www.roadkil.net/program.php?ProgramID=12

Comment: i tried it ,it showed that Unable to locate program entry point InterlockedCompareExchange@12 on libstdc++-6.dll,i will follow your advise to try the Roadkil's Disk Image,thanks for your kind heart!